# How to pass a wire up a motor shaft?

Tags: connector

I'm thinking of buying a [DC Motor](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12144) to play with. I'm wondering is there any way to pass a wire up to electronics spinning on the shaft?

I'd love to pass 4 wires (vcc, dcc, clk an data) lines from electronics sitting next to the motor up to some electronics being rotated by the motor.

I'm wondering if there is a connector of some kind that would let me do such a thing.

Comment: A motor shaft is solid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You are looking for a 4-pole slip-ring.

If you want the motor shaft to pass through the slip-rings you will need a hollow version.

[image]

*Figure 1. Hollow slip-ring.*

Comment: So [this](http://www.fabricast.com/fabricast-products/stock-slip-ring-assemblies/self-contained-assemblies-0-50-inch-bore/) is just about what I would want. On the other hand I can't find anyplace that sells them.

Comment: You'll have to try harder! If you're on a tight budget then look up "DIY slip-rings" on Google image search.